# Async and await on a ReplaySubject

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs

I'm trying to create a convenience getter method for the current value of a `ReplaySubject`. I thought I'd make use of the `.toPromise` method and use the async await syntax on that. Something like this:

```
get latestResults(): number[] {
  return (async () => {
    return await this._result$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  })();
}
```

However I'm getting errors suggesting that await isn't actually taking care of the promise:

> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type
>   'number[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.

Also tried:

```
async getLatestResults(): number[] {
  return await this._result$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
}
```

And a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1nyvzu). The "Cached Results" section is supposed to be using the logic in question.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to hide the async / await nature of promises? As soon as you start awaiting promises, your async has to bubble up through functions that await it. Can your describe your ultimate goal?

Comment: @KurtHamilton Yeah, basically that. End goal is that I don't want other components to have to care that the value they're looking for is being stored in a ReplaySubject. It seemed like a Promise would be the way to go for that.

Comment: Afraid not! Something has to subscribe to subjects, and something has to await promises (or call `.then`). Rules of the universe, unfortunately.

Comment: The way to handle that is to say .asObservable() which will give you an observable. Don't turn observables into promises. You will thank yourself later.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Ok, I guess I had a misunderstanding about await resolving the promise.

Comment: @mgm87 Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. I typically do use Observables. I was just hoping I could cut down on some boiler plate code.

Comment: Looking at your example, it seems you are using `latestResults` in an `*ngFor` loop. If this is the case, you can just stick to Observables and use the `async` pipe in the html template to take care of subscription and unsubscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don´t use toPromise() and async / await.
Instead always return Observable.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TestState  {

  private readonly _result$ = new ReplaySubject<number[]>(1);

  get results(): Observable<number[]> {
    return this._result$.asObservable();
  }

  updateResults(newResults: number[]): void {
    this._result$.next(newResults);
  }

  getLatestResults(): Observable<number[]> {
    return await this.results.pipe(take(1));
  }
}
```

Don´t subscribe in that Facade, don´t implement OnDestroy in that Facade, you should do this kind of behavior inside a component.
You should have only one observable and those cached data flows into that one stream that you print in html via async pipe.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  value: number;
  result$: Observable<number[]>;
  subject: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  constructor(private readonly _test: TestFacade) {
    this.result$ = this._test.pipe(takeUntil(this.subject)).getLatestResults();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subject.next();
    this.subject.complete();
  }
}
```

Please provide more information about that caching with a real life example. I have never had a situation that I would need a ReplaySubject. For example if you want to cache http requests there are rxjs operators for it (shareReplay). If you want to cache data in the state you can hold some kind of validUntil information that will say that data needn´t to be reload until some Date.

Comment: I'll accept this. It's not what I was looking for, but based on comments it's not worth going down the road I was trying.